# Which banks in Europe have online banking via smartcard and plan to keep it?

Tags: online-banking

In the European Union there are a lot of banks that have online banking platforms that allow to login via E.Identifier also called PIN Sentry in the UK, but they are moving their platform towards mobile app banking. Some banks already work only via mobile app banking.

Few small banks are going against this trend by using smartcard security, mainly smartcard security based on [EIDAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EIDAS). But most of them are specialised banks. Are there in the EU big general banks that offer smartcard online banking and are not planning to phase it out?

Please avoid comments or answers over which is better. I only want to know if the option exists and will exist in the future.

**Update:** 
I see that the question was closed as if it was seeking product recommendation. But this is not the case. The purpose of the question is to asses how much choice consumers can have over an important aspect of their banking services. Which unfortunately seem very poor, banks have become so powerful that they can give people no choice.

Comment: Don't you want to narrow "Europe" down a bit (to a country)? It's typically fairly hard to open an account in a different EU member state without being a resident of that state, so answers for countries other than your own are likely to be next to useless.

Comment: If there are no such banks Europe wide narrowing it down is even worse. Anyway I worked as a freelancer in different European countries,I take for granted that the resident limitation exists, but it is not an extreme limitation. Furthermore now there are some banks called "neo banks" that offer accounts to all citizens within the European economic area, but unfortunately they all rely only on mobile phones so I ruled them out. On a second thought I can narrow it down to the EU.

Comment: We certainly can't answer what their plans are. And "which" is a Shopping Question, which is out of scope; you can research that as easily as we can, and any answer we give now may be wrong next week.